# Get neighbors image pixel coordinates

Tags: windows, image, opencv, filter, pixel

I'm developing a CUDA application that works with image pixels.
My problem is this: for example I want to get the 8-neighbors of a pixel i,j and I have 3x3 threads. I want that the first thread takes the pixel i-1,j-1 , the 2nd thread takes the pixel i-1,j .... Is there a formula that can help me? I would a variable windows (3x3, 5,5) so i wouldn't a static matrix with the coordinates. 
Thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

int w = 3;
for(int n=0;n<w*w;n++){
 ( i-n/w-w/2,     j-n%w-w/2)
}

Notice the division iin the i and modulus (%) in the j